# Difference between two arrays (suppressed and added lines)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 php arrays :

First One :

```
    <?php
    while ($res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un = mysql_fetch_array($sql_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un)) {
        $myTAB_last_update_moins_un[$compteur_risk_moins_un] = array(
            'MyRisk_level_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_level_xls'],
            'MyRisk_SN_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_SN_xls'],
            'MyRisk_content_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_content_xls']
        );

        $compteur_risk_moins_un++;
    }
```

Second One :

```
    <?php
    while ($res_liste_risks_last_update = mysql_fetch_array($sql_liste_risks_last_update)) {
        $myTAB_last_update[$compteur_risk] = array(
            'MyRisk_level_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_level_xls'],
            'MyRisk_SN_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_SN_xls'],
            'MyRisk_content_xls' => $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_content_xls']
        );

        $compteur_risk++;
    }
```

The structure of this 2 arrays is the same.

For information, I fill these 2 arrays with 2 mysql queries. The data are present on the same table.

i would like to get the difference between this 2 arrays :

- The new line present on the second array (myTAB_last_update)  (regarding the value present on first array $myTAB_last_update_moins_un)
- The suppressed line (no more present) on the second array (myTAB_last_update)  (regarding the value present on first array $myTAB_last_update_moins_un)

I tried several method like :

- PHP : array_diff_assoc  => This solution give me the good number of line suppressed but not the good value. And this solution not return the new line.
- PHP : 2 nested foreach (sorry i'm not sure that nested is the good word in English)
- MYSQL : create a mysql query with 2 SELECT and 1 IN

I never found any solution to my problem.

To be more clear, here a easiest explanation :

Array_1 :

```
0   value1  value2
1   value1  value2
2   value1  value2
3   value1  value2
4   value1  value2
5   value1  value2
```

Array_2 :

```
0   value1  value2
2   value1  value2
3   value1  value2
4   value1  value2
5   value1  value2
6   value1  value2
```

On the second array :

=> line 2 was suppressed

=> line 6 was added

i want to do that with my own arrays.

Have you got any ideas ?

Best regards,

Florent.

Comment: Hello, Sorry but my first line "Hello all" was deleted from my post.

Answer (score 2):

What's about that ?

```
$added = array_diff_key($new, $old);
$deleted = array_diff_key($old, $new);

foreach(array_keys($added) as $no_row){
   echo "Line ".$no_row." added";
}
foreach(array_keys($deleted) as $no_row){
   echo "Line ".$no_row." deleted";
}
```

Waiting your feedback ;)

Comment: "Hello" deleted too

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I will test your method tonight. I will keep you inform as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello, i just test your method.

Comment: As is said, i test your method. At the begining 184 Lines. I deleted the line N°1. The result was => Line 183 deleted. After that i added one line (on the first position) => line 183 added. And thrid test : I deleted the first line and added a new line at the first position => No result. So for me it doesn't work. I don't think if it was clear but i want to test if a line (the 3 value) was deleted or added. So for my last test, the script should print : 1 line added and 1 line deleted. And for the first and the second test, the number of line is ok but not the good line (the id).

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was a little idiot, I've forgot you was creating rows ID from 0 to X for the twice arrays (red number on your Array_2 example are not 023456 but 012345 like the first).
So we can't use it to compare lines.

I test this code and it seem good:

```
$added = array_diff($tab2, $tab);
$deleted = array_diff($tab, $tab2);
foreach(array_keys($added) as $no_row){
    echo "Line ".($no_row+1)." added<br>";
}
foreach(array_keys($deleted) as $no_row){
    echo "Line ".($no_row+1)." deleted<br>";
}
```

It print the line deleted in array1 and added in array2. Problem will be if you have 2 different rows with same values ...

Comment: Thank you for your update. I will test in 1à minutes and i will give you an update.

Comment: Hello. Your solution doesn't work for me. But i found a solution to do what i want. It's not very good solution in my mind but it's work. I will add a new answer with all details.

Answer (score 1):

So i found a solution for my problem. Perhaps it's not a conventionnal way but it works.

So you could find below an explanation :
- Modify my 2 arrays with a concatenation

```
 while($res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un = mysql_fetch_array($sql_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un))
 {
    $chaine_update_moins_un = $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_level_xls'] . '__' . $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_SN_xls'] . '__' . $res_liste_risks_last_update_moins_un['MyRisk_content_xls'];

    $myTAB_last_update_moins_un[$compteur_risk_moins_un] = $chaine_update_moins_un;
    $compteur_risk_moins_un++;      
 }


 while($res_liste_risks_last_update = mysql_fetch_array($sql_liste_risks_last_update))
 {
    $chaine_update = $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_level_xls'] . '__' . $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_SN_xls'] . '__' . $res_liste_risks_last_update['MyRisk_content_xls'];

    $myTAB_last_update[$compteur_risk] = $chaine_update;
    $compteur_risk++;           
 }
```

Then :

```
 $added = array_diff($myTAB_last_update, $myTAB_last_update_moins_un);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($added);
 echo '</pre>';




 $deleted = array_diff($myTAB_last_update_moins_un, $myTAB_last_update);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($deleted);
 echo '</pre>';
```

So now, i can print the lines added and the lines suppressed.

After that i will realize an explode and it will be good ;-)

Thank you for your help.

Best regards,

Florent.

Comment: Ah I think array_diff can't compare when value is an array. WP !